# country specific auto language changer & currency converter

Tags: magento-1.9, multicurrency

We have an e-commerce .in domain. now we are planning to sell our product internationally for which we are planning to open multi sub-domain. the content & image of .in domain will be in all the sub-domain but pricing will change. so kindly suggest steps.

Comment: Please give more information on your question. What do you mean by sub domain? All you content is the same but you will only change the price?

Comment: Correct I want to show different price base on countries...